# Unable to open javascript search engine results on a new window

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search

I'm using a javascript search engine from this [script page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut130.shtml) that allows me to select different providers/search engines to perform a google like search, but I'm trying to make it open in a new window after I press the send button, without success.

I've already tried to use:

```
target="_blank"
```

in `<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="startSearch()" target="_blank">` and nothing happens, or:

```
<form name="searchForm" target="_blank">
```

Nothing!

I've also tried to use _new instead of _blank and didn't work either.

Finally, I've tested what suggested on [w3schools.com example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp) but unfortunately again a failure.

Can you please, guys, help? Thanks!

Comment: You aren't submitting a form. You aren't following a link. The target attribute won't do anything unless the JavaScript uses it.

Comment: Uhm, that script page is ages old - it still shows Altavista and lacks Google, DuckDuckGo and Bing. Lots of those search engines won't work anymore. Forget about it - offer one good search for your users.

Comment: Johannes Jander, the script works as is =) I just want it to open in a new window.

Comment: Quentin, what if I change/add something somewhere in the searchString or in the function section of the script? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, you can use the `window.open();` method to open the search in a new window, here's some updated HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="#" id="search-form">
    <p><label>Search for: <input type="text" id="q" /></label></p>
    <p><label>Search from: <select id="engine">
        <option selected="selected" value="http://www.google.com/search?q=">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.bing.com/search?q=">Bing</option>
        <option value="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=">Yahoo!</option>
        <option value="http://search.aol.com/aol/search?q=">AOL</option>
    </select></label></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Send" id="send" /></p>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var ID = function(str){return(document.getElementById(str));};
    ID('send').addEventListener('click', function(){
        var search = ID('q').value, select = ID('engine'), engine = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if(!search) {
            alert('Please include a search string');
        } else {
            window.open(engine + search);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Just make sure to call that at the end of the page or put it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event or something.

[MDN Docs on window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Faino, I've used your answer as a solution to my problem, even if it was not by decoding my initial script. But, it works fine for me. Many thanks!

Comment: Do i need to do anything else to close this as the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

try something this if you want to open a new tab link by your button-

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
    <input type="button" value="Send" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works in the example you provided but not for the example I gave =)

Comment: what you want? do you want to achieve it by `onclick` event of the button?

Comment: `onclick` button has already a function, can I duplicate it without causing conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

To open the link in a new window, since you are using a `<form>` instead o an `<a>` link, you have to change the javascript shown in the example, first adding an ID to the form so it is easilly accessible via the DOM:

```
<form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" target="blank">
```

Then, change the last javascript line so instead of the location.href, it changes the form's action and submits it:

```
document.getElementById("searchForm").action = finalSearchString;
document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vj99ux9e/